# How to create an "automatic" matrix depending on the user's input?

Tags: java, matrix

I'm new to java and I really need help with this. I've already read many similar questions and tried but I still can't get anything done.

What I'm trying to do is a matrix given a message, for example:
if the user writes "Hello guys" the letters get converted into numbers, then those numbers should be put on a matrix 3xN:

Hello world --> (H=7, e=4, l=11, l=11, o=14, " "[whitespace]=26, g=6, u=21, y=25, s=19)

I already got the part of the message converted into numbers done, but i'm stuck with the matrix thing.

Those numbers should get put on a 3xN matrix:

```
7  11  6   19
4  14  21  26
11 26  25  26
```

The spare spaces should be whitespace *(in this case 26)*

If anyone could help me or just give an idea i would truly appreciate it.

Comment: You should include the code you've already written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Define the number of columns by the length of the string
2. Create the matrix 3*N
3. Set the cells of the matrix (first by columns then by rows) using the conversion rules:

- if character in the string is a space or the end of the input string has been reached, use 26
- otherwise, use the difference of the current character in lower case with 'a'

Example implementation:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();

int cols = (int) (Math.ceil(str.length() / 3.0));

int [][] matrix = new int[3][cols];

int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        matrix[j][i] = x >= str.length() || str.charAt(x) == ' ' ? 26 : str.charAt(x) - 'a';
        x++;
    }
}
for (int[] row : matrix) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

For input "Hello guys", the output is:

```
[7, 11, 6, 18]
[4, 14, 20, 26]
[11, 26, 24, 26]
```

*Note:* `u` should be coded as 20, `y` as 24, `s` as 18.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This one really did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate the number of columns and fill it in:

```
int rows = 3;
int cols = (int)Math.ceil((double)s.length() / rows);
int [][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
    char c = i < s.length() ? s.charAt(i) : ' ';
    matrix[i % rows][i / rows] = !Character.isAlphabetic(c) ? 26 : (Character.isUpperCase(c) ? c - 'A' : c - 'a');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
int n = numbers.length;
int groups = n/3;
int remainder = n%3;
String s1="",s2="",s3="";
for(int i =0;i<groups;i++){
    s1+=" "+String.valueOf(numbers[i*3+0]);
    s2+=" "+String.valueOf(numbers[i*3+1]);
    s3+=" "+String.valueOf(numbers[i*3+2]);
}
if(remainder==1){
    s1+=" "+String.valueOf(numbers[groups*3]);
    s2+=" 26";
    s3+=" 26";
}
if(remainder==2){
    s1+=" "+String.valueOf(numbers[groups*3]);
    s2+=" "+String.valueOf(numbers[groups*3+1]);
    s3+=" 26";
}
System.out.println(s1.strip());
System.out.println(s2.strip());
System.out.println(s3.strip());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr =  {7,4,11,11,14,26,6,21,5,19} // your array of calculated values from the input string;
int count = 0;
int n = (int) Math.ceil((double)arr.length/3);
int[][] matrix = new int[3][n];
    for (int col=0; col<n; col++) {
        for(int row=0; row< 3; row++ ) {
            int val = count < arr.length ? arr[count++] : 26;
            matrix[row][col] = val;
        }
    }
```